# Search optimisation over oracle DB

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

We have set of customer tables like customer, customer address, customer-communication, customer profession (oracle 11g).

Front end will provide few details like 'email-id', 'f-name', 'city', 'state' to search in the DB and return matching customer details.

all tables contains more than 10 coulmns and when the matching emailid, f-name, city, state are found we need to return the details for that customer.

the return details are spread over all 4 tables and we need to join all 4 tables to get the details to return. (ex: we need to retun cust-id, appt num, city, state, phone numbers, profession deatisl)

comm-metchod - can have like email, phone, fax and
comm-method-values - will contain have thier values

also customer can have multiple addresses(with different address-id) and professions!

Issue here is the data size and join is taking more time. we are considering to have materialsed views but still the size of view will grow incredibly when a customer can multiple addresses, email addressed and professions.

looking for suggestion to solve the search complexity.

table are like -

Tab-name:CUSTOMER
Cust_id
F-Name
L-Name
Pref-Name
prefix
suffix
gender
blah1
blah2
blah3

---

Tab-name:CUST_ADDR
Cust-id
Cust-addr-id
street
appt num
City
State
Country
blah4
blah5
blah6

---

Tab-name:CUST_COMMUNICATION
cust-id
Cust-addr-id
comm-method
comm-method-value
blah7
blah8

---

Tab-name:CUST_PROFESSION
cust-id
profession-code
profession description
Comments-txt
blah9
blah10

---

Comment: show some SELECTs please

Comment: show some sample data and desired output of query for that data

Comment: "all tables contains more than 10 rows" ? I'm irresistably tempted to say "Is that when you ran out of fingers ?". Sorry. Can we assume the missing word is "million".

Answer (score 1):

You need to plan out what queries will be permitted; that is what are the minimum required fields and what indexes are there to support them.

I can't imagine a search on just city or state would provide a useful result. You'd have too many matches.

Email-Id will be very selective, so you use one query if they supply an email id. The query will drive from the small number of matched customer_communication records, up to the parent customer and then down to the other child records.

First-Name plus Last-Name will be acceptably selective, so use a second query if they supply these but NOT an email_id (which would be using the first query)
First-Name plus city plus state may be acceptable, so a third query for that
Last-Name plus city plus state may be acceptable, so a fourth query for that

Most of the indexes will probably be cached in memory. You'll probably get down to a handful of physical IOs per query. If you need to get it lower than that, then look into materialized views or table clusters (ie one cluster on CUST_ID with all the tables stored as part of that cluster).

Comment: Thanks Gary, one of the search criteria is with email-id, f-name, l-name, city, state and profession-code. return parameters for matching customer is cust-id, pref-name, appt num, street name, city, email-ids and profession code.